# Stencil CLI - Installation Error - Stencil Init - command not found

Tags: command-line-interface, bigcommerce

I tried to install stencil CLI on my Mac Sierra 10.12.6
I keep on getting an error when trying to do `stencil init`

```
-bash: stencil: command not found
```

I have installed:

- node -v  -  v9.1.0
- npm -v  -  5.5.1

Please help ;-)  it used to run on my mac not sure what I did wrong.... it is not working anymore

Answer (score 2):

It could be that Stencil CLI was installed in a local directory instead of globally. You can try to rerun the command to install the CLI: `npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli` and be sure that the `-g` isn't omitted.

You can also try entering `echo $NVM_DIR` and if it returns nothing in the terminal, run `source ~/.bash_profile` and then try `stencil init` again.

Comment: still did not work.  I wish I could share a screen with you so you can help me figure this out....

Comment: Stencil CLI hasn't been tested on node versions after 7.9.0. If you roll back to that version of node, do you get a different result?